# golang: build specific version w/ -o flag

Tags: go

I am trying to build the package `github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe` and have the resulting executable named `dlv-dap`.

Under older versions of go (pre 1.16) I was able to accomplish this by running the following commands.

- `go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe`
- `go build -o dlv-dap github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe`

Under `v1.17` this no longer works, instead the command `go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe` throws the following error

*go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.*

Reading the information link provided in the error it seems there is no longer a way to download/build a golang package with a customized name (e.g. `-o my_custom_named_executable`).

Is my understanding correct or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Actually you just have to do `go install` instead of `go get`, with the same syntax. Now you can only run `go get` in a go module directory to add a dependency.

Comment: `go install` does not accept the `-o` flag... as stated I want a custom named executable, `go install` does not offer this level of control

Comment: Is manually renaming the executable after installing an option?

Comment: Yes indeed, you are confusing install and build. You don't even need the build command,  `go install` will add the binary to your `$GOPATH/bin` directory without you needing to build it yourself.

Comment: `go build` still exists to compile from sources, what you can do if you want to build it yourself is clone the project and run your go build command from the root.

Comment: Since you cannot process `replace` directives outside of a module, the only universal way to install a package is to run `go install` from within the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions to do what you want:

### First solution: `go install`

This will install the `dlv` executable to your `$GOPATH/bin` directory.

```
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@2f13672765fe
```

### Second solution: install from source:

```
git clone git@github.com:go-delve/delve.git
cd delve
git checkout 2f13672765fe
go build -o dlv ./cmd/dlv
```

This will build `dlv` executable to the root of the project.

### Run Delve DAP

Use `dlv dap` subcommand, `dlv-dap` is just an alias to that.

Comment: First Solution: results in an executable named `dlv` not `dlv-dap`

Comment: Second Solution: this seems to work

Comment: Indeed, this is the official name of the executable. `dlv-dap` is now a subcommand of `dlv`, just run `dlv dap` instead.

Comment: If you are on Linux or Macos you can add an alias for `dlv-dap` to run `dlv dap` with `alias` command added to your shell configuration (e.g, `.bashrc`)

Answer (score 0):

The name given to the binary is defined in the mod-file. In this case the mod-file contains:

```
module github.com/go-delve/delve
```

If you clone the repository using git you can change this to:

```
module github.com/go-delve/dev-dap
```

If you now start

```
go build
```

the new name will be assigned.